# ASP.NET application performing full page reload on each request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I expected my web application to behave like a "Single Page App", in that the entire screen would not turn white between each page load, but rather render just the new section of the page as per:

```
<div id="mainSection">
    <!-- Render individual pages -->
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

and the links on my `_Layout.cshtml` page:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Some Page", "Index", "Page")</li>
```

Now one other point is that the application appears to behave correctly in Firefox only. The application does not perform a full page reload in Firefox, but in Chrome or IE it does. The application is running on IIS.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "new section". What kind of requests are you sending?

Comment: I see how you could confuse sections and Render methods to only update parts of the page. However, you need to use Ajax calls to update specific parts without reloading the full page. Do a search for `ASP.NET MVC Ajax` and you'll find lots of articles and walkthroughs on how to achieve partial page loading and other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

`@Html.ActionLink` is just a helper method that creates a link with a URL to a particular controller and action (so you don't have to hard-code URLs everywhere.)

It produces a link that's pretty much like any other:

```
<a href="/Page/Index">Some page</a>
```

so it's expected that clicking on it should load that page in the browser, even if it's the page you're already on. (Like if you click on the stackoverflow logo over and over - it's going to keep reloading the same page.)

What's peculiar is that it's *not* doing a reload in Firefox. Are you sure it's not just loading really fast?

---

When one of your views uses a layout, `@RenderBody()` in the layout tells it where to render your view within the layout. That's just specifying how your page fits into the layout, but it doesn't mean that the only that part is going to reload.

---

Try [this link](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/05/ajax-partial-views-asp-net-mvc.aspx) for what you're actually trying to do.

- In JavaScript, make an Ajax call to a controller
- The controller renders a partial view (a view with no layout) and returns HTML as the result of the Ajax call
- Your JavaScript gets the result of the Ajax call and replaces the contents of some `<div>` with the new HTML.

That way the page never refreshes, but instead just one part of it gets updated.

Then there are all sorts of JavaScript libraries like AngularJs that automate that for you. But I'd recommend getting your own first test case working so you can see how it's happening before moving on to something else.

Comment: Yes, Firefox behaves as expected. It does not reload the header, navigation bar or footer, only the inner section of the page.